# api platform graphql exceptions

Tags: symfony, error-handling, graphql, api-platform.com

I am using Api Platform with graphql.

Symfony Flex, Symfony 4.4, api-platform/core v2.5.6.

When I throw exceptions in prod mode the only thing I see is the general 'Internal server error' message instead of my own exceptions messages.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      }
    }  
}
```

How is it possible when I throw my own exceptions to see the messages?

```
throw new \Exception('Show this exception message');
```

Thanks

Comment: what version of Symfony?

Comment: Thx for your reaction. Symfony version 4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [custom error normalizer](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#custom-exception-normalizer) to add the message you want when a supported exception is thrown.

Comment: Thx for your response. I've already tried that. Added that sample code and registered the custom normalizer as a service. But if I dd() in the normalize method it won't get there. Do I miss something?

Comment: Which version of API Platform are you using?

Comment: api-platform/core v2.5.6, symfony flex, symfony 4.4

Comment: It's only available for 2.6. Please try to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it have breaking changes from 2.5.6 to 2.6.2? Don't see anything about it on github.

Comment: There is a few, mainly the validation status code (422 instead of 400), and the need to have a proper identifier in a resource.